# SVG draw one letter at a time

Tags: css, animation, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to recreate the following behavior, specifically I want the letters to come in one letter at a time, from left to right as if someone was actually writing it on the screen.

http://codepen.io/itsnorbat/pen/vNEEYZ

I know that this part of svg code is the word hello:

```
<path id="fontshape" d="m 250 252 c 0 0 25.833 -21.854 33 -6.59 c 2.244 4.778 -43.583 107.903 -43.583 107.903 s 20.416 -48.943 27.583 -51.667 c 5.042 -1.916 42.333 2.175 53 -3.079 s 31.667 -58.746 31.667 -58.746 s -49.991 106.985 -38.334 113.492 c 14.228 7.941 77.913 -39.622 64.667 -50.334 c -8.667 -7.009 -17.608 4.216 -21 8.334 c -1.747 2.121 -21.333 44.027 2.667 42.014 s 91.817 -93.427 96.306 -103.723 c 4.669 -10.712 1.947 -11.996 -0.639 -12.291 c -11.721 -1.335 -37.539 40.442 -53 103.333 c -3.426 13.935 6.667 17.333 15.333 9.333 s 76.855 -91.35 79 -100.226 c 2.393 -9.902 -7.731 -15.378 -17 0.226 c -11.271 18.976 -36.465 82.571 -36 92.667 c 0.263 5.689 2.403 18.828 15.333 6.667 c 19.894 -18.71 42.666 -47.667 42.666 -47.667 s -21.522 22.389 -22 45 c -0.245 11.592 16.631 5.965 23.274 0.667 c 5.081 -4.052 17.727 -21.334 15.06 -36.667 s -13.334 -10.001 -16.667 1.333 s 5 10 17 8 s 17 -13.666 17 -14.333" fill="none" stroke="none" />
```

and this is the animation:

```
.animatedfont {
fill:none;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:3;
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-linejoin:round;
stroke-miterlimit:100;
stroke-dasharray: 2000;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
-webkit-animation: dash 4.9s linear forwards;
-o-animation: dash 4.9s linear forwards;
-moz-animation: dash 4.9s linear forwards;
animation: dash 4.9s linear forwards;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
}
to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

Here is my effort: 
https://jsbin.com/qelonotoxu/1/edit?html,js,output

and my animate code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.st0{

    fill:none;
    stroke:#000000;
    stroke-dasharray: 2000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
    -webkit-animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
    -o-animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
    animation: dash 10s linear forwards;

}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
    }
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

 </style>
```

As you can see all of the letters are animated at the same time and if I change my stroke-dashoffset = 0, it does not animate at all.  Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this question and trying the codepen for the desired behavious as shown in the question, the animation doesn't work properly in Firefox (v44.0.2). To see it properly, you have to change `@-webkit-keyframes` in the codepen code to just `@keyframes`.

Comment: This is what you want: https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how you can animate each of these letters (well, actually I stopped after three letters) separately using as few changes as possible to the svg `path` and only using css-based animation `keyframes`. However, let me say from the start, this is *painful* and *not* the way to animate letters in the way you want. Perhaps the end lesson will be: "Try something else."

To see the animation in action, click "Run code snippet" below.

I had to do several things. Animating from start-to-end (or end-to-start) along a `path` that has multiple 'moveto' commands within it (i.e. multiple `"M"`s) using the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute is undoable. This is because the stroke dasharray re-starts after every 'moveto' and, I believe, you have no control over that. Thus, the `path` had to have all the 'moveto' commands eliminated. This meant, though, that with a solid stroke there would be ugly connections from where one letter "ends" to where the next letter "begins". These needed to be gotten rid of by inserting a dasharray gap at each jump to the next letter where the original 'moveto' commands were. I did that (painfully) by trial and error. Then multiple animation `keyframes` were required to animate one letter after the next. To start, one dash was gradually lengthened to complete the first letter, followed by an essentially infinite gap to hide the remaining letters. Then a correct gap was inserted to the second letter, and the process was repeated.

Part of the problem here is that the letters in your path are separated by 'moveto' commands. In the codepen that you linked to in your question showing the behaviour you were looking for, you'll see that the path is actually continuous, with no gaps between letters...a much easier thing to css-animate by changing `stroke-dashoffset`. If that's what you want, great, but you're going to have to fundamentally change (i.e. go back to Illustrator, etc.) the image you're using, which you may or may not be willing or able to do.

You still *could* animate each letter in this image separately. However, if you did, I think the best strategy would be to separate the single monolithic `path` element into individual `path`s for each "letter". You would then have to animate the first letter (possibly using `stroke-dashoffset`, but possibly another way) and, when that is finished, start the next letter, etc. I suppose you could try to do this using strictly css-based animations. However, in the end, I think it would probably be better (more efficient, more broadly applicable, etc.) to use some sort of JavaScript-based animation where you could control things more programmatically.

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 10000000;
  }
  40% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 10000000;
  }
  40% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 0 10000000;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 295 10000000;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 295 53 0 10000000;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 295 53 113 10000000;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 295 53 113 42 0 10000000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 580 50 295 53 113 42 60 10000000;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 268.382 72.239" style="enable-background:new 0 0 268.382 72.239;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path id="path" class="st0" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M37.627,7.954c-2.16,1.632-4.032,3.54-5.616,5.724c-1.584,2.185-3.013,4.525-4.284,7.02
  c-1.272,2.497-2.425,5.088-3.456,7.776c-1.033,2.688-2.052,5.389-3.06,8.1c-1.008,2.712-2.077,5.353-3.204,7.92
  c-1.128,2.568-2.437,4.98-3.924,7.236l0.144,0.144c1.487-1.392,3.107-2.952,4.86-4.68c1.751-1.728,3.552-3.528,5.4-5.4
  c1.847-1.872,3.683-3.768,5.508-5.688c1.824-1.919,3.564-3.792,5.22-5.616c1.656-1.823,3.179-3.564,4.572-5.22
  c1.392-1.656,2.544-3.132,3.456-4.428c0.288-0.432,0.731-1.08,1.332-1.944c0.6-0.864,1.26-1.812,1.98-2.844
  c0.72-1.031,1.512-2.099,2.376-3.204c0.864-1.104,1.728-2.1,2.592-2.988c0.864-0.888,1.703-1.62,2.52-2.196
  c0.815-0.576,1.559-0.864,2.232-0.864c0.24,0,0.456,0.084,0.648,0.252c0.191,0.169,0.288,0.421,0.288,0.756
  c0,0.288-0.121,0.612-0.36,0.972c-0.241,0.36-0.517,0.72-0.828,1.08c-0.313,0.36-0.661,0.709-1.044,1.044
  c-0.385,0.336-0.72,0.625-1.008,0.864c-2.016,1.776-3.697,3.732-5.04,5.868c-1.344,2.137-2.532,4.405-3.564,6.804
  c-1.033,2.401-1.956,4.86-2.772,7.38c-0.816,2.52-1.692,5.04-2.628,7.56s-1.992,4.993-3.168,7.416
  c-1.177,2.424-2.653,4.716-4.428,6.876l0.144,0.144c2.208-1.487,4.632-3.12,7.272-4.896c2.64-1.775,5.292-3.683,7.956-5.724
  c2.664-2.04,5.256-4.212,7.776-6.516c2.52-2.304,4.788-4.716,6.804-7.236c2.016-2.52,3.696-5.148,5.04-7.884
  c1.343-2.736,2.16-5.568,2.448-8.496c-0.529-0.288-0.925-0.708-1.188-1.26c-0.265-0.551-0.396-1.14-0.396-1.764
  c0-0.767,0.275-1.404,0.828-1.908c0.551-0.504,1.235-0.756,2.052-0.756c0.576,0,1.067,0.133,1.476,0.396
  c0.407,0.264,0.744,0.601,1.008,1.008c0.263,0.409,0.443,0.864,0.54,1.368c0.096,0.504,0.144,0.997,0.144,1.476
  c0,2.113-0.588,4.345-1.764,6.696c-1.177,2.353-2.7,4.705-4.572,7.056c-1.872,2.353-3.996,4.692-6.372,7.02
  c-2.376,2.329-4.777,4.5-7.2,6.516c-2.424,2.016-4.764,3.864-7.02,5.544c-2.256,1.681-4.201,3.072-5.832,4.176
  c-1.152,0.769-2.4,1.597-3.744,2.484c-1.345,0.889-2.653,1.777-3.924,2.664c-1.272,0.889-2.46,1.753-3.564,2.592
  c-1.104,0.84-1.992,1.596-2.664,2.268l-0.432-0.576c1.728-2.399,3.215-5.004,4.464-7.812c1.248-2.808,2.399-5.711,3.456-8.712
  c1.055-3,2.124-6.012,3.204-9.036c1.08-3.024,2.292-5.904,3.636-8.64l-0.144-0.072c-1.584,1.969-3.48,4.201-5.688,6.696
  c-2.208,2.497-4.584,5.076-7.128,7.74c-2.545,2.664-5.148,5.304-7.812,7.92c-2.664,2.617-5.245,5.052-7.74,7.308
  c-0.72,0.673-1.357,1.321-1.908,1.944c-0.552,0.625-1.044,1.177-1.476,1.656c-0.432,0.48-0.853,0.864-1.26,1.152
  c-0.409,0.288-0.876,0.432-1.404,0.432c-0.673,0-1.008-0.241-1.008-0.72c0-0.288,0.167-0.576,0.504-0.864
  c0.335-0.288,0.72-0.6,1.152-0.936c0.432-0.335,0.852-0.659,1.26-0.972c0.407-0.312,0.708-0.636,0.9-0.972
  c1.392-2.399,2.58-4.919,3.564-7.56c0.983-2.639,1.908-5.292,2.772-7.956c0.864-2.664,1.775-5.328,2.736-7.992
  c0.959-2.664,2.099-5.244,3.42-7.74c1.319-2.495,2.927-4.883,4.824-7.164c1.896-2.279,4.236-4.356,7.02-6.228l-0.144-0.144
  c-1.584,0.72-3.432,1.393-5.544,2.016c-2.113,0.624-4.284,1.308-6.516,2.052c-2.232,0.745-4.428,1.548-6.588,2.412
  c-2.16,0.864-4.093,1.861-5.796,2.988c-1.705,1.128-3.072,2.424-4.104,3.888c-1.033,1.465-1.548,3.157-1.548,5.076
  c0,1.776,0.479,3.145,1.44,4.104c0.959,0.961,2.207,1.44,3.744,1.44c1.104,0,2.111-0.216,3.024-0.648
  c0.911-0.432,1.692-1.008,2.34-1.728c0.648-0.72,1.14-1.536,1.476-2.448c0.335-0.911,0.504-1.824,0.504-2.736
  c0-0.288-0.012-0.576-0.036-0.864c-0.024-0.288-0.061-0.576-0.108-0.864h0.864c0.047,0.288,0.083,0.576,0.108,0.864
  c0.023,0.288,0.036,0.576,0.036,0.864c0,1.2-0.216,2.316-0.648,3.348c-0.432,1.033-1.02,1.933-1.764,2.7
  c-0.745,0.769-1.632,1.357-2.664,1.764c-1.033,0.408-2.149,0.612-3.348,0.612c-2.016,0-3.684-0.576-5.004-1.728
  c-1.321-1.152-1.98-2.808-1.98-4.968c0-2.16,0.587-4.02,1.764-5.58c1.175-1.56,2.772-2.94,4.788-4.14
  c2.016-1.199,4.392-2.279,7.128-3.24c2.736-0.96,5.639-1.872,8.712-2.736c2.543-0.72,4.596-1.319,6.156-1.8
  c1.56-0.479,2.796-0.888,3.708-1.224c0.911-0.335,1.572-0.612,1.98-0.828c0.407-0.216,0.684-0.419,0.828-0.612L37.627,7.954
                                                                                                                        
L89.682,8.241L64.194,46.113l0.144,0.144c0.959-1.199,2.088-2.58,3.384-4.14
  c1.296-1.559,2.7-3.035,4.212-4.428c1.512-1.392,3.107-2.567,4.788-3.528c1.68-0.96,3.359-1.44,5.04-1.44
  c2.927,0,4.392,1.465,4.392,4.392c0,0.769-0.277,1.681-0.828,2.736c-0.552,1.056-1.249,2.172-2.088,3.348
  c-0.84,1.177-1.741,2.365-2.7,3.564c-0.961,1.201-1.861,2.365-2.7,3.492c-0.841,1.128-1.537,2.185-2.088,3.168
  c-0.552,0.984-0.828,1.812-0.828,2.484c0,0.529,0.155,0.972,0.468,1.332c0.312,0.36,0.731,0.54,1.26,0.54
  c1.104,0,2.315-0.348,3.636-1.044c1.32-0.695,2.688-1.607,4.104-2.736c1.415-1.127,2.819-2.387,4.212-3.78
  c1.392-1.392,2.675-2.772,3.852-4.14c1.176-1.368,2.232-2.664,3.168-3.888s1.62-2.22,2.052-2.988l0.432,0.144
  c-0.529,0.913-1.272,2.016-2.232,3.312c-0.96,1.296-2.052,2.664-3.276,4.104c-1.224,1.44-2.545,2.869-3.96,4.284
  c-1.417,1.417-2.833,2.689-4.248,3.816c-1.417,1.128-2.82,2.041-4.212,2.736c-1.393,0.695-2.689,1.044-3.888,1.044
  c-1.249,0-2.268-0.385-3.06-1.152c-0.792-0.767-1.188-1.823-1.188-3.168c0-0.959,0.276-2.016,0.828-3.168
  c0.551-1.152,1.248-2.315,2.088-3.492c0.839-1.176,1.739-2.352,2.7-3.528c0.959-1.175,1.859-2.292,2.7-3.348
  c0.839-1.056,1.536-2.027,2.088-2.916c0.551-0.888,0.828-1.644,0.828-2.268c0-0.768-0.216-1.296-0.648-1.584
  c-0.432-0.288-0.96-0.432-1.584-0.432c-1.2,0-2.532,0.444-3.996,1.332c-1.464,0.889-2.977,2.052-4.536,3.492
  c-1.561,1.44-3.108,3.06-4.644,4.86c-1.537,1.8-2.988,3.612-4.356,5.436c-1.368,1.825-2.568,3.553-3.6,5.184
  c-1.033,1.632-1.836,3.024-2.412,4.176h-4.68c2.64-4.127,5.352-8.327,8.136-12.6c2.783-4.271,5.555-8.52,8.316-12.744
  c2.76-4.223,5.46-8.388,8.1-12.492c2.639-4.104,5.136-8.028,7.488-11.772L89.682,8.241
 
L129.928,39.85c-1.152,1.296-2.448,2.329-3.888,3.096c-1.44,0.769-2.856,1.152-4.248,1.152
  c-1.344,0-2.497-0.299-3.456-0.9c-0.961-0.6-1.705-1.307-2.232-2.124h-0.144c-0.48,1.825-1.368,3.769-2.664,5.832
  c-1.296,2.064-2.844,3.96-4.644,5.688c-1.8,1.728-3.78,3.168-5.94,4.32c-2.16,1.152-4.368,1.728-6.624,1.728
  c-2.064,0-3.625-0.6-4.68-1.8c-1.057-1.199-1.584-2.808-1.584-4.824c0-1.055,0.264-2.279,0.792-3.672
  c0.528-1.392,1.26-2.795,2.196-4.212c0.936-1.415,2.04-2.808,3.312-4.176c1.271-1.368,2.651-2.592,4.14-3.672
  c1.487-1.08,3.06-1.944,4.716-2.592c1.656-0.648,3.323-0.972,5.004-0.972c1.968,0,3.492,0.576,4.572,1.728
  c1.08,1.152,1.667,2.641,1.764,4.464c0.096,1.104,0.612,2.124,1.548,3.06s2.219,1.404,3.852,1.404c1.44,0,2.796-0.36,4.068-1.08
  c1.271-0.72,2.459-1.656,3.564-2.808L129.928,39.85

L93.713,53.746c0,1.249,0.24,2.232,0.72,2.952
  c0.479,0.72,1.199,1.08,2.16,1.08c1.296,0,2.58-0.348,3.852-1.044c1.271-0.695,2.496-1.607,3.672-2.736
  c1.176-1.127,2.268-2.412,3.276-3.852c1.008-1.44,1.883-2.927,2.628-4.464c0.744-1.536,1.332-3.036,1.764-4.5
  c0.432-1.464,0.648-2.796,0.648-3.996c0-1.008-0.252-1.86-0.756-2.556c-0.504-0.695-1.285-1.044-2.34-1.044
  c-1.008,0-2.088,0.324-3.24,0.972c-1.152,0.648-2.316,1.5-3.492,2.556c-1.177,1.057-2.293,2.281-3.348,3.672
  c-1.056,1.393-2.005,2.833-2.844,4.32c-0.84,1.488-1.501,2.977-1.98,4.464C93.952,51.058,93.713,52.449,93.713,53.746

L153.688,7.954c-4.273,6.48-7.992,12.084-11.16,16.812c-3.168,4.728-5.881,8.772-8.137,12.132
  c-2.256,3.36-4.104,6.132-5.543,8.316c-1.44,2.185-2.568,3.973-3.384,5.364c-0.817,1.393-1.38,2.496-1.692,3.312
  c-0.313,0.816-0.468,1.512-0.468,2.088c0,1.2,0.528,1.8,1.584,1.8c1.199,0,2.604-0.492,4.212-1.476
  c1.608-0.983,3.336-2.328,5.184-4.032c1.848-1.703,3.732-3.696,5.652-5.976c1.92-2.279,3.791-4.716,5.615-7.308l0.793,0.288
  c-1.729,2.448-3.553,4.812-5.473,7.092c-1.92,2.281-3.77,4.261-5.543,5.94c-2.353,2.208-4.382,3.816-6.085,4.824
  c-1.704,1.008-3.252,1.512-4.644,1.512c-1.488,0-2.556-0.336-3.204-1.008c-0.648-0.671-0.972-1.559-0.972-2.664
  c0-1.008,0.18-2.052,0.54-3.132c0.36-1.08,0.972-2.376,1.836-3.888c0.864-1.512,2.003-3.348,3.42-5.508
  c1.415-2.16,3.168-4.812,5.256-7.956c2.088-3.143,4.548-6.887,7.38-11.232c2.832-4.344,6.096-9.443,9.791-15.3H153.688

L170.174,39.418c-0.72,1.2-1.62,2.52-2.699,3.96c-1.08,1.44-2.305,2.869-3.673,4.284
  c-1.367,1.416-2.832,2.784-4.392,4.104c-1.561,1.32-3.181,2.496-4.86,3.528c-1.681,1.033-3.372,1.848-5.075,2.448
  c-1.705,0.6-3.373,0.9-5.005,0.9c-2.016,0-3.576-0.517-4.68-1.548c-1.104-1.031-1.656-2.507-1.656-4.428
  c0-2.112,0.636-4.332,1.908-6.66c1.271-2.328,2.892-4.475,4.86-6.444c1.968-1.968,4.127-3.6,6.479-4.896
  c2.352-1.296,4.608-1.944,6.769-1.944c1.199,0,2.135,0.252,2.808,0.756c0.672,0.504,1.008,1.236,1.008,2.196
  c0,1.152-0.624,2.268-1.872,3.348s-2.771,2.064-4.571,2.952c-1.801,0.889-3.733,1.681-5.796,2.376
  c-2.064,0.696-3.889,1.212-5.473,1.548c-0.528,0.961-0.961,2.041-1.296,3.24c-0.336,1.201-0.504,2.401-0.504,3.6
  c0,0.576,0.06,1.141,0.18,1.692c0.119,0.553,0.312,1.057,0.576,1.512c0.264,0.457,0.623,0.828,1.08,1.116
  c0.456,0.288,1.02,0.432,1.692,0.432c1.584,0,3.443-0.515,5.58-1.548c2.135-1.032,4.308-2.412,6.516-4.14
  c2.207-1.728,4.32-3.695,6.336-5.904c2.016-2.208,3.744-4.488,5.185-6.84L170.174,39.418

L158.51,35.602
  c0-0.672-0.18-1.176-0.54-1.512c-0.359-0.335-0.804-0.504-1.332-0.504c-1.008,0-2.1,0.396-3.275,1.188
  c-1.177,0.792-2.34,1.776-3.492,2.952c-1.152,1.177-2.196,2.437-3.132,3.78c-0.937,1.344-1.645,2.545-2.124,3.6
  c1.055-0.191,2.376-0.563,3.96-1.116c1.584-0.551,3.107-1.235,4.572-2.052c1.463-0.816,2.724-1.764,3.779-2.844
  C157.982,38.014,158.51,36.85,158.51,35.602

L193.934,39.489c-1.439,2.304-3.108,4.597-5.004,6.876c-1.896,2.281-3.973,4.333-6.228,6.156
  c-2.257,1.825-4.717,3.301-7.381,4.428c-2.663,1.127-5.507,1.692-8.531,1.692c-1.152,0-2.232-0.144-3.24-0.432
  s-1.885-0.72-2.628-1.296c-0.744-0.576-1.344-1.308-1.8-2.196c-0.456-0.888-0.685-1.932-0.685-3.132
  c0-1.248,0.408-2.376,1.225-3.384c0.816-1.008,1.919-1.512,3.312-1.512c0.72,0,1.308,0.18,1.764,0.54s0.685,0.9,0.685,1.62
  c0,0.672-0.169,1.249-0.504,1.728c-0.337,0.48-0.841,0.72-1.513,0.72c-0.528,0-0.948-0.144-1.26-0.432
  c-0.312-0.288-0.517-0.648-0.611-1.08c-0.529,0.288-0.888,0.708-1.08,1.26c-0.191,0.552-0.288,1.116-0.288,1.692
  c0,1.681,0.637,2.941,1.908,3.78c1.271,0.84,2.699,1.26,4.283,1.26c1.009,0,1.884-0.204,2.628-0.612
  c0.744-0.407,1.368-0.936,1.872-1.584s0.876-1.404,1.116-2.268c0.239-0.864,0.36-1.728,0.36-2.592c0-0.911-0.156-1.859-0.468-2.844
  c-0.313-0.983-0.661-1.955-1.045-2.916c-0.385-0.959-0.744-1.908-1.079-2.844c-0.337-0.936-0.505-1.811-0.505-2.628
  c0-1.055,0.217-2.003,0.648-2.844c0.432-0.839,1.02-1.548,1.764-2.124s1.596-1.02,2.556-1.332c0.959-0.312,1.968-0.468,3.023-0.468
  c1.92,0,3.479,0.421,4.681,1.26c1.199,0.84,1.8,1.957,1.8,3.348c0,1.249-0.468,2.16-1.404,2.736
  c-0.936,0.576-1.979,0.864-3.132,0.864c0.288-0.527,0.54-1.163,0.756-1.908c0.216-0.744,0.324-1.428,0.324-2.052
  c0-0.959-0.301-1.764-0.9-2.412c-0.601-0.648-1.452-0.972-2.556-0.972c-1.393,0-2.425,0.421-3.096,1.26
  c-0.672,0.841-1.008,1.861-1.008,3.06c0,1.057,0.181,2.064,0.54,3.024c0.36,0.961,0.78,1.92,1.26,2.88
  c0.432,0.96,0.827,1.944,1.188,2.952c0.36,1.008,0.54,2.137,0.54,3.384c0,0.912-0.205,1.789-0.612,2.628
  c-0.408,0.84-0.948,1.609-1.62,2.304c-0.671,0.696-1.428,1.285-2.267,1.764c-0.84,0.48-1.692,0.792-2.556,0.936l0.144,0.144
  c2.592-0.288,5.063-1.044,7.416-2.268c2.352-1.224,4.548-2.711,6.588-4.464c2.04-1.751,3.924-3.672,5.652-5.76
  c1.728-2.088,3.24-4.14,4.536-6.156L193.934,39.489

L212.726,33.297h4.68c-1.776,2.497-3.48,4.921-5.112,7.272c-1.632,2.353-3.084,4.525-4.355,6.516
  c-1.272,1.992-2.293,3.744-3.061,5.256c-0.768,1.512-1.151,2.7-1.151,3.564c0,1.249,0.647,1.872,1.943,1.872
  c1.009,0,2.292-0.492,3.853-1.476c1.56-0.983,3.251-2.34,5.076-4.068c1.823-1.728,3.695-3.744,5.615-6.048
  c1.92-2.304,3.744-4.752,5.473-7.344l0.432,0.144c-1.296,1.969-2.82,4.093-4.572,6.372c-1.752,2.28-3.588,4.404-5.508,6.372
  c-1.92,1.969-3.841,3.612-5.76,4.932c-1.92,1.321-3.721,1.98-5.4,1.98c-1.393,0-2.412-0.349-3.06-1.044
  c-0.648-0.695-0.972-1.523-0.972-2.484c0-0.671,0.107-1.332,0.323-1.98c0.217-0.648,0.443-1.307,0.685-1.98l-0.145-0.072
  c-0.624,0.673-1.403,1.452-2.34,2.34c-0.936,0.889-1.943,1.717-3.023,2.484c-1.08,0.769-2.196,1.417-3.349,1.944
  c-1.151,0.527-2.257,0.792-3.312,0.792c-1.776,0-3.024-0.553-3.744-1.656s-1.08-2.351-1.08-3.744c0-1.967,0.623-4.14,1.872-6.516
  c1.247-2.376,2.832-4.608,4.752-6.696c1.919-2.088,4.007-3.827,6.264-5.22c2.256-1.392,4.393-2.088,6.408-2.088
  c0.96,0,1.8,0.133,2.521,0.396c0.72,0.265,1.319,0.625,1.8,1.08c0.479,0.457,0.852,0.972,1.116,1.548
  c0.263,0.576,0.468,1.177,0.611,1.8h0.145L212.726,33.297

L189.182,53.458c0,1.104,0.227,1.956,0.684,2.556
  c0.456,0.601,1.092,0.9,1.908,0.9c0.815,0,1.775-0.299,2.88-0.9c1.104-0.6,2.256-1.404,3.456-2.412
  c1.199-1.008,2.387-2.171,3.563-3.492c1.176-1.319,2.22-2.724,3.133-4.212c0.911-1.487,1.655-3,2.231-4.536
  c0.576-1.536,0.864-2.999,0.864-4.392c0-1.104-0.312-1.944-0.937-2.52c-0.624-0.576-1.393-0.864-2.304-0.864
  c-1.439,0-3.049,0.625-4.824,1.872c-1.776,1.249-3.456,2.844-5.04,4.788c-1.584,1.944-2.916,4.093-3.995,6.444
  C189.722,49.042,189.182,51.297,189.182,53.458

L249.588,7.954c-4.272,6.48-7.992,12.084-11.16,16.812c-3.168,4.728-5.88,8.772-8.136,12.132
  c-2.257,3.36-4.104,6.132-5.544,8.316c-1.439,2.185-2.568,3.973-3.384,5.364c-0.816,1.393-1.381,2.496-1.692,3.312
  c-0.312,0.816-0.468,1.512-0.468,2.088c0,1.2,0.527,1.8,1.584,1.8c1.199,0,2.604-0.492,4.212-1.476
  c1.607-0.983,3.336-2.328,5.185-4.032c1.847-1.703,3.731-3.696,5.651-5.976c1.92-2.279,3.791-4.716,5.616-7.308l0.792,0.288
  c-1.728,2.448-3.553,4.812-5.472,7.092c-1.921,2.281-3.77,4.261-5.544,5.94c-2.353,2.208-4.381,3.816-6.084,4.824
  c-1.705,1.008-3.253,1.512-4.645,1.512c-1.488,0-2.556-0.336-3.204-1.008c-0.647-0.671-0.972-1.559-0.972-2.664
  c0-1.008,0.18-2.052,0.54-3.132s0.972-2.376,1.836-3.888c0.864-1.512,2.004-3.348,3.42-5.508c1.415-2.16,3.168-4.812,5.256-7.956
  c2.088-3.143,4.548-6.887,7.38-11.232c2.832-4.344,6.096-9.443,9.792-15.3H249.588

L266.074,39.418c-0.72,1.2-1.62,2.52-2.699,3.96c-1.08,1.44-2.305,2.869-3.673,4.284
  c-1.367,1.416-2.832,2.784-4.392,4.104c-1.561,1.32-3.181,2.496-4.86,3.528c-1.681,1.033-3.372,1.848-5.075,2.448
  c-1.705,0.6-3.373,0.9-5.005,0.9c-2.016,0-3.576-0.517-4.68-1.548c-1.104-1.031-1.656-2.507-1.656-4.428
  c0-2.112,0.636-4.332,1.908-6.66c1.271-2.328,2.892-4.475,4.86-6.444c1.968-1.968,4.127-3.6,6.479-4.896
  c2.352-1.296,4.608-1.944,6.769-1.944c1.199,0,2.135,0.252,2.808,0.756c0.672,0.504,1.008,1.236,1.008,2.196
  c0,1.152-0.624,2.268-1.872,3.348s-2.771,2.064-4.571,2.952c-1.801,0.889-3.733,1.681-5.796,2.376
  c-2.064,0.696-3.889,1.212-5.473,1.548c-0.528,0.961-0.961,2.041-1.296,3.24c-0.336,1.201-0.504,2.401-0.504,3.6
  c0,0.576,0.06,1.141,0.18,1.692c0.119,0.553,0.312,1.057,0.576,1.512c0.264,0.457,0.623,0.828,1.08,1.116
  c0.456,0.288,1.02,0.432,1.692,0.432c1.584,0,3.443-0.515,5.58-1.548c2.135-1.032,4.308-2.412,6.516-4.14
  c2.207-1.728,4.32-3.695,6.336-5.904c2.016-2.208,3.744-4.488,5.185-6.84L266.074,39.418

L254.41,35.602
  c0-0.672-0.18-1.176-0.54-1.512c-0.359-0.335-0.804-0.504-1.332-0.504c-1.008,0-2.1,0.396-3.275,1.188
  c-1.177,0.792-2.34,1.776-3.492,2.952c-1.152,1.177-2.196,2.437-3.132,3.78c-0.937,1.344-1.645,2.545-2.124,3.6
  c1.055-0.191,2.376-0.563,3.96-1.116c1.584-0.551,3.107-1.235,4.572-2.052c1.463-0.816,2.724-1.764,3.779-2.844
  C253.882,38.014,254.41,36.85,254.41,35.602z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```